# Android->Activity->Button_Back Нужно полностью закрыть приложение

Tags: android, многопоточность, activity, android-asynctask

У меня есть активити A и B.Активити A показывается 2 секунды,потом автоматически сменяется на активити B.Если нажать кнопку back(),то закроется активити A,и мы выйдем на рабочий стол,и через 2 секунды запускается активити B.

Вопрос: **Как сделать так - если я закрываю активити A,то закрывается и все приложение?**

Comment: отменяйте запланированное задание на открытие **B** при закрытии **A**

Comment: @metalurgus Это понятно,но как это реализовать?)

Comment: Зависит от того, как реализовано планирование задания

Comment: @metalurgus Я так понимаю,что мне нужно переписать метод onBackPressed?
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    } Я его переписал таким способом,но мне нужно,чтобы я выходил в меню Андроида,а не на рабочий стол(

Comment: Я же сказал, что зависит от того, как вы показываете А через 2 секунды

Comment: ну так чем приведенное мной решение Вам не подходит?

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю как там у Вас это реализовано, но вот предыдущий вариант с небольшими изменениями:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mPostDelayedRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        mPostDelayedRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(mPostDelayedRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPostDelayedRunnable);
    }
}
```

Надо всего лишь в `onBackPressed` удалить Callback.